# Setting a total upload limit on users - PHP

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm implementing a file sharing system where only users are uploading and downloading files from server. I have an idea around what I want, which is to set an upload limit on users.

In my database there is a field called limit_upload and is subtracted whenever an upload is complete. Let's say the user has a 5 GB of free space at the beginning and starts to decrease every time something is uploaded and increase back when deleting. Is this the right way of doing it? I don't want to go on implementing this before making sure it's going to work.

If yes, are there better ways of applying the idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP can limit the size of *individual* uploads easily through INI settings.

If you want to limit *total* uploads over a period of time, then yes you'll need to track that yourself.

If you store user uploads in separate directories, then you could also just monitor the size of each user's folder, rather than adding/subtracting manually from a value in the DB.

Comment: I see, so even if files were public, the link on my server would be ./public/user_id/file_name? Because I'm creating private groups which each will have a directory, ./private/group_id/user_id/file_name ?

Comment: @Atieh Sure that's one way to do it.

Comment: @Atieh It's completely up to you how you structure your directories. That structure will make it quite easy to get total space used by user and by group, so sure it looks good to me.